Exclude unnecessary classes from executable JARs compiled from monorepo with Maven
I have a monorepo that has multiple executable classes and their shared dependencies.  I can create JARs with dependencies so that they can easily be deployed and executed.  However, all of the compiled JARs seem to include all of the classes from the repo, even classes that are not required (neither directly nor indirectly) by a specific main class.
Can I tell Maven to just include those classes that are actual dependencies of a the main class I'm compiling to an executable JAR?
My pom.xml looks something like this:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Tools</name>
  <description>Tools we use</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- More dependencies... -->
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Tool1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>Tool1</finalName>
                            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.example.tools.Tool1</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Tool1</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>Tool2</finalName>
                            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.example.tools.Tool2</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <!-- More profiles... -->
    </profiles>
</project>


Your dependency to junit is not of scope test... the configuration for maven-compiler and the properties <maven.compiler.source> contradict each other? If you like to have different executables with different dependencies you should create separate modules and build each tool in a separate module within a multi module build... that also has the advantage to get rid of the profiles...

Can your problem be solved by using different dependencies for the different profiles? Dependencies can be set on the profile level. See this question.

@khmarbaise Thanks for pointing out the issues. Concerning the suggested multi-module build, I'll have a look here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html.

@Lii Maybe partly.  I think that the other classes inside the repo would still be included.

@ThomasW: Ah, I understand. I though it was only the dependency classes that you wanted to exclude. An more light-weight alternative to dividing the project into separate modules might be to exclude source files based on the profile using the compiler plugin. See this answer.

@Lii Given the choice, I'd probably accept that unnecessary classes from the repo are still included rather than manage this manually.  I'll definitely consider your first suggestion.
